# How to show a jQuery mobile Dialog from javascript (GPS)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an app with JQM and PhoneGap. At beginning, the app checks if GPS is enabled. If not, it should open a JQM dialog box.

The standard dialog from JavaScript works, but I want the JQM dialog, but it doesn't work.

That's my code:

```
<!-- PhoneGap 2.9.1  -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

---

From PhoneGap Documentation:
I've insert one line at the end: $.mobile.changePage('#dialogGPS', { transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        Hello
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#home').on("pageshow", function() {  
        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        }

        // onSuccess Geolocation
        //
        function onSuccess(position) {
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                                'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                                'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                                'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                                'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                                'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                                'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                                'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
        }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');

            $.mobile.changePage('#dialogGPS', { transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });
        }
    });
    </script>

</div>
```

---

The dialogGPS role:

```
<div data-role="dialogGPS">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <h1>Dialog</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">OK</a> 
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your dialog markup is wrong. Instead of:

```
<div data-role="dialogGPS">
```

try

```
<div id="dialogGPS" data-role="page">
```

> #### Here is a **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/GaHda/)**